# Scheduling jobs with fixed start and end time on limited machines

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, coloring, network-flow

The problem: Given n jobs with fixed start and end times, and k machines each capable of doing only one job at a time, find if it is possible to schedule all n jobs on these k machines using network-flow.

I know there are many similar questions here but none seem to exactly fit the specifications of this particular problem.

My general idea was to use a graph where each node represents a job and the directed edges out of this node will be connected to a job that starts after it ends. I'm assuming that's the basis but I'm struggling with juggling the 3 constraints:

1. Cannot have two jobs on a single machine that intersect.
2. Must use a maximum of k machines.
3. Max flow possible should be n.

Every solution I tried fails because one of these constraints, would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea about jobs as nodes and directed arcs if the first job ends by the time the next job starts.  Now split each node $i$ into two nodes $i'$ and $i''$, with a directed arc from $i'$ to $i''$ that has a lower bound of $1$.  Introduce a source node $s$ with supply $k$ and a sink node $t$ with demand $k$, with an arc from $s$ to each $i'$, an arc from each $i''$ to $t$, and an arc from $s$ to $t$.  All arcs except $(s,t)$ have an upper bound of $1$.  The jobs can all be scheduled if and only if there is a feasible flow.